# Dimension of Vector Spaces

Tags: matrices

Can anybody help me finding out the dimension of the vector spaces:

1. A: A is $n\times n$ real upper triangular matrices.
2. A: A is $n\times n$ real symmetric matrices.
3. A: A is $m\times n$ real matrices.

Comment: do you know the notion of a vector basis?

Comment: Yes, I do know.

Comment: Try computing the bases for these spaces. The dimension will simply be the number of vectors in the basis. *Hint*: For 3, this is the set of products of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that it has dimension $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$. That is, if $\mathcal{A}_n$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathcal{A}_m$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$, then $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{A}_n \cup \mathcal{A}_m$ is a basis for the space of $m \times n$ matrices.

Comment: ok let me consider some random matrices that are upper triangular, symmetric and real and then find out the basis....may be through that I can generalise.

Comment: Good, see what properties must hold in specific cases to write a basis.

Answer (score 0):

You may understand the notion of dimension from this perspective:

> For a vector in this linear space, what's its degree of freedom? That is to say, how many "free" (or *independent*) components does it have?